# VB SQL refresh dataset from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, dataset, sql-delete

I have a problem with updating my dataset with data from sql database.
I am deleting some rows with sql query, but dataset is not refreshing in the same application run. 
Selected rows are deleted in database, but they are still showing in datagrid in my application.

Comment: Delete them from the DataSet/DataTable and update the database from that.

Comment: @OneFineDay, what you are suggesting is the complete opposite of what Plutonix said.  You're suggesting retrieving data, making independent changes to the database and then retrieving data again.  Plutonix is suggesting doing it the proper way, i.e. retrieving data, making changes to that copy of the data and then saving those changes back to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously doing things the wrong way around because the deleted rows should be gone from your grid even before they are deleted from the database.  You need to understand that a `DataTable` doesn't have a live connection to a database.  If you populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid and then completely separately make changes to the database, why would the grid change?  The grid is showing what's in the `DataTable` and the `DataTable` hasn't changed.  It knows nothing about the changes you made to the database.

The proper way to do it is to make the changes to the `DataTable` first, which will be reflected in the grid.  You then save your changes from the `DataTable` back to the database and everything is then in sync.  As you've chosen to keep it secret from us what you're actually doing, I can't tell you exactly what you need to change.  That is the principle you need to implement though, and I'd suggest that you do it from scratch, rather than trying to change what you have piecemeal.